# JavaScript filter object when property is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects and I'm trying to filter and return only the objects in which the 'IsSubstitute' property has value true.

```
    [
       {
         EndTime: "16:00",
         IsSubstitute: false,
         OutletId: 619777,
         StartTime: "05:00",
         VisitDate: "2014-05-30",
         id: "168de242-d031-49f2-96d1-803154d0df1e"
       },
       {
         EndTime: "17:00",
         IsSubstitute: true,
         OutletId: 619755,
         StartTime: "05:00",
         VisitDate: "2014-05-30",
         id: "168de242-d031-49f2-96d1-803154d0dabc"   
       },
       {
         EndTime: "18:00",
         IsSubstitute: true,
         OutletId: 619722,
         StartTime: "05:00",
         VisitDate: "2014-05-30",
         id: "168de242-d031-49f2-96d1-803154d0ddfg"   
       }
       // and so on...
    ]
```

I've tried this with no luck:

```
data = $.grep(data, function (e) {
       return e.IsSubstitute = false;
});
```

Any help, please!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `=` which sets the value but not checks for equality.

Use `===`, which means strictly equal to:

```
data = $.grep(data, function (e) {
    // --------------------v
    return e.IsSubstitute === true;

    // or simply return e.IsSubstitute;
});
```

Comment: hey thanks, don't know why I didn't think about it ===, beginner's mistake! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try native `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
arr.filter(function(v){ return v.IsSubstitute == true});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built-in `.filter` method of JS arrays.  Using your example, you would use:

```
data = data.filter( function(item) { return item.IsSubstitute === true })
```

Not all browsers support filter, but all modern ones (IE9, FF, Chrome) do.

Comment: If it is not supported by old browsers, so why *should* he use it then?

Comment: Because, not everyone needs to support pre-IE9 environments.  As it turned out, the chosen answer is really the best response given the original asker's circumstance, but as the other respondent also suggested the `.filter` built-in method, then I think it could be considered a standard approach to the problem.